# Axios ignora cors desde express node js

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, axios, cors

Tengo un backend y un frontend en node js y quiero decidir que dominio puede hacer peticiones get, post, etc, desde axios o fetch.

Desde el backend con el módulo cors configuro el origin con el dominio que tendrá el permiso de enviar peticiones.

Si desde el frontend desde un index.html uso axios o fetch si respeta el cors, pero si uso axios o fetch desde el servidor node js con express ignora cors y deja ver la petición.

Ejemplo:

main.js Backend

```
import express from "express"
import cors from "cors"

const app = express()

const allowedOrigins = ["http://127.0.0.1:3500"]

const credentials = (req, res, next) => {
    const origin = req.headers.origin
    if (allowedOrigins.includes(origin)) {
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true)
    }
    next()
}

const corsOptions = {
    origin: (origin, callback) => {
        if (allowedOrigins.indexOf(origin) !== -1 || !origin) {
            callback(null, true)
        } else {
            callback(new Error("Not allowed by CORS"))
        }
    },
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200
}

app.use(credentials)

app.use(cors(corsOptions))

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.json({
        status: "success",
        message: "Backend"
    })
})

app.listen(4000, () => {
    console.log(`Backend is running on port 4000 http://127.0.0.1:4000`)
})
```

main.js Frontend

```
import express from "express"
import axios from "axios"

const app = express()

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    axios
        .get("http://127.0.0.1:4000")
        .then(response => {
            res.json(response.data)
        })
        .catch(error => {
            res.json(error)
        })
})

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log(`Frontend is running on port 3000 http://127.0.0.1:3000`)
})
```

Esto debería dar error cors, pero no, al final muestra el json y es lo que no quiero.

Espero puedan ayudarme, gracias de antemano :(

Answer (score 0):

Podrías usar CORS de esta manera

```javascript
app.use(cors());

var whitelist = ["http://127.0.0.1:5000"]

var corsOptions = {
  origin: function (origin, callback) {
    if (whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
      callback(null, true)
    } else {
      callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'))
    }
  }
}

app.get("/", cors(corsOptions),async (req, res) => {
  await axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:4000")
    .then(response => {
      res.json({ data: response.data })
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.json(err)
    })
})
```

Comment: Este código lo colocaría en el backend o en el frontend, aunque la protección debería venir del backend no del frontend :(

Comment: Si debes colocarlo en tu backend

Comment: No me funciona :(

Comment: En si lo que quiero es bloquear desde el backend peticiones que vengan desde cualquier servidor node js express con axios.